# How to generate a production build of an API done with NESTJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, production, nestjs

I am generating the production version of an API I made using the NESTJS framework and would like to know which files I should upload to the server. When I run the "npm run start: prod" compile it generates the "dist" folder but I tried to run only with it but it is not enough to run my application. Do I need to upload all files to the server? I did several tests removing the folders I used during development but only managed to run in production mode when I was all the same in dev mode.

I looked in the documentation for something about this but found nothing. can anybody help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Honestly, you should only really need the dist folder as that's the JS 'complied' files. To run your application, commonly you'd use this command `node dist/main.js`. As to what files you upload it's up to you. Me personally, I use a lot of continuous integration so I would just clone to repo into my container/server and use `yarn start:prod`. This is so everytime I deploy I'm generating the required files to run in a production environment.

Like @Kim Kern mentioned, some node modules are native built using node-gyro; so it's also always best to build your node_modules on the server/container when deploying. Your deployment script should look something like this

```sh
git clone git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git /var/www/
cd /var/www/
node -v && \
yarn && \
yarn build && \
yarn start:prod
```

The above script should

1) pull the required repo into a 'hosted' directory
2) check the node version
3) install node_modules and build native scripts etc
4) build the production distribution
5) run the production JS scripts

If you look in your package.json file you'll notice the different scripts that are run when you use `yarn start`, `yarn start:dev` and `yarn start:prod`. When in dev you'll notice the use of `ts-node` which is a typescript node runner type thing (can't remember the correct phrase). Also the `start:dev` script uses nodemode to restart the `ts-node` script. You'll also see the `start:prod` script uses `node dist/main.js` and that the `prestart:prod` script runs `rm -rf dist && tsc` which removes the dist folder and 'compiles' the javascript required for a production environment.

However, the drawback of a typescript application on your server without continuous integration is that there is the possibility of typescript compilation errors which you wouldn't see or know about until running the prod scripts. I would recommend putting a procedure in place to compile the javascipt from typescript before making a deployment as you don't want to delete the current dist build before knowing the next release will build and run!

Comment: Another drawback of building on the server is that it takes tons and tons of memory for Webpack to finish the Typescript type checking. For example Node.js runs fine on a AWS t2.micro with 1GB ram, but when building a node app even a 2gb ram server crashes. You could use `transpileOnly: true` in webpack config. Then the app builds in seconds but you haven o type checking.

Answer (score 18):

For me this approach worked and all you need is the `dist` folder for this:

- Create a prod build of your application using `npm run start:prod`, this would create a `dist` folder within your application source
- Copy the `dist` folder to your server.
- For getting all the `node_modules` dependencies on your server just copy your `package.json` file into the `dist` folder (that you have copied onto the server) and then run `npm install` from there.
- If you are using `pm2` to run your node applications just run `pm2 start main.js` from within the `dist` folder

Comment: Why do you need to copy the package json into the dist folder? You can run npm install from root and run your app in the dist folder from root, too.

Comment: Hi @Mick of-course you are correct, your approach works if you don't mind having your source code also on the server. But in situations where you need bundle only the `dist` files onto your servers the approach you mentioned might not be a viable solution. Thats why you need to have the `package.json` install your node_modules for you to run your application using your `dist` files. I hope that helps.

Comment: I believe, `dist` folder doesn't contain machine specific code, Correct?

Comment: `pm2` + `dist` is clean

Answer (score 8):

@edit Just a short comment that came to my mind when getting back to this answer: Typically you would use PM2 as process manager for NodeJS applications in production.
You then just create an ecosystem.config.json file and use this to startup all your processes.
An example will follow soon!

Just use the Nest-CLI and build with

```
nest build
```

Afterwards you get a dist folder with the compiled Code.
You can then place it on a server an run e.g. with PM2 proccess manager:

```
production=true pm2 start dist/main.js
```

In former command the environment variable *production* is set to *true*. That could e.g. be usefull when running the Nest.js server over HTTPS.

If you want to run a HTTPS secured server you also have to include the certificates in the starting process of the server. When the environment variable production is set and true the certificates get included in the starting proccess of the Nest.js application in main.ts like following:

```
async function bootstrap() {
let appConfig = {}
if (process.env.production) {
    console.log('process env production: ', process.env.production)
    const httpsOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/certs/letsencrypt/live/testtest.de/privkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/certs/letsencrypt/live/testtest.de/fullchain.pem'),
    }
    
    // prod config
    appConfig = {
        httpsOptions,
    }
}

const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
    appConfig,
)

app.enableCors()
app.setGlobalPrefix('v1')

await app.listen(3300)
}
bootstrap()
```

Answer (score 5):

Mostly, you will only need the dependencies in `node_modules`. You should build the libraries on your server though instead of copying them from your dev machine. Libraries like `bcrypt` have machine specific code and probably won't run on a different machine. ([30% of the npm libraries](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/node-js-8-big-improvements-for-the-debugging-and-native-module-ecosystem-58454861f2fc) have native bindings.)

So for your deployment I would recommend to checkout your git repository on your server and then just run `npm run start:prod` (which builds the project every time) directly there.

Comment: omg. After 6 hours I saw your "machine specific" phrase. I wish I knew that. Thanks!

Comment: A drawback of building on the server is that it takes tons and tons of memory for Webpack to finish the Typescript type checking. For example Node.js runs fine on a AWS t2.micro with 1GB ram, but when building a node app even a 2gb ram server crashes. You could use `transpileOnly: true` in webpack config. Then the app builds in seconds but you haven o type checking. The best option might be to build the javascript before deployment but run npm/yarn install on the server?

Answer (score 4):

We don't build our application on production, but instead build it when creating our docker container.

The steps for us roughly are:

1. Run `npm install` and whatever tooling you need to build the application.
2. Create docker container and copy `dist/`, `node_modules` and `package.json`
3. Inside the docker container run `npm rebuild bcrypt --update-binary`

Comment: This seems smarter. You don't want the production build to end up with slightly different modules after the build passed on CI. Production builds should be EXACTLY what was built in CI, with no code downloaded from the internet to production.

Comment: @MarkStosberg isn't it a problem that the code has been built in a different environment than the one it'll run in?

Answer (score 0):

We are using NX for monorepo where we hold our API's. And we use docker for our images and containers. When we have to create docker image, only run: `npx nx build <project>` and this generate build on `dist/apps/<project>`. This folder goes to the docker image, with the package.json and that's it. You don't need to add node_modules, because they are on the package.json. Just be sure to include `npm install` on your Dockerfile.

Comment: The caution with `npm install` is it doesn't actually install exactly the version defined in the `package.json` unless you pin versions.  It's always better to run `npm ci --production` and copy the node_modules into the image - this will guarantee consistent versions.

`npm install` where you have `"lib": "^1.0.0"` will upgrade `"lib"` to `v1.0.1` and i've had mongoose introduce breaking changes on patch versions.